# Apache forbidden access with Docker

Tags: apache, docker, server

I build this image on docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'

services:
  webserver:
  build: ./docker/webserver
  image: image_name
  ports:
    - "80:80"
    - "443:443"
  volumes:
    - /Users/user_name/Sites/site:/var/www/html
```

And have this commands on Dockerfile

```
 FROM php:7-apache
 RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y libpng-dev && apt-get 
 install -y libcurl4-openssl-dev
 RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql gd curl
 RUN a2enmod rewrite
 RUN service apache2 restart
```

BUT I get

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access / on this server.
Apache/2.4.10 (Debian) Server at localhost Port 80
```

when I go to localhost.

I work with Mac.
I have used the docker files to other project and all worked great.
what am I missing?

Log response

> Cannot serve directory /var/www/html/: No matching DirectoryIndex
>   (index.php,index.html) found, and server-generated directory index
>   forbidden by Options directive

Comment: what does the log say?

Comment: @whites11 thank you for your response. edited the question for the log response.

Answer (score 25):

Looks like apache is not finding an index page to serve. Ensure your volume mapping is correct (enter the image with `docker exec` and check contents of `/var/www/html` folder). If your files are there, ensure that you have an `index.html` or `index.php` file for apache to be served.

Answer (score 6):

If you change to apache document root to something non-standard outside of `/var/www` you will need to grant access in your vhost:

```
DocumentRoot /workspace/my-project

<Directory /workspace/my-project>
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```