# Apache 403 Forbidden You don't have permission to access / on this server

Tags: apache, docker

I am new to Docker and Apache and am trying to execute a very simple program that would display a web page on my localhost. However, I keep getting a `403 Forbidden error` saying that

> "You don't have permission to access / on this server"

. I am using `Apache/2.4.25 (Debian)` Server at localhost Port `5002`. The path to the directory is `~/tutorial/product`. I have read many solutions on here, and have tried all of them, but none of them have worked for me.

**/etc/apache2/apache2.conf**

```
<Directory /var/www/html>
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

**/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf**

```
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/signature

<Directory /var/www/signature/>
   Allowoverride all
   Order allow,deny
   Allow from all
   Require all granted
</Directory>

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
```

I have included the permissions at each directory in the path using `ls -l`:

***~/tutorial***

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|     -rwxr-xr-x      |docker-compose.yml|
|---------------------|------------------|
|     drwxr-xr-x      |    product       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|     drwxr-xr-x      |    website       |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

***~/tutorial/products***

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|     -rwxr-xr-x      |     api.py       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|     -rwxr-xr-x      |    Dockerfile    |
|---------------------|------------------|
|     -rwxr-xr-x      |     index.php    |
|---------------------|------------------|
|     -rwxr-xr-x      | requirements.txt |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

Comment: whats the user group? are you using ubuntu? centos? if you're on ubuntu, it should be www-data:www-data. if not do a chown www-data:www-data -r /directory. is ~/tutorial/product under /signature?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu. I tried the chown command but it says `invalid option --'r'`. ~/tutorial/product is in home

Comment: try sudo chown -R www-data:www-data ~/tutorial

Comment: The command went through, but still getting the permission issue. Do I actually need a directory called `signature`? Because I don't have one

Comment: Looks like apache is not finding an index page to serve. Ensure your volume mapping is correct (enter the image with docker exec and check contents of /var/www/html folder). If your files are there, ensure that you have an index.html or index.php file for apache to be served. - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46000003/apache-forbidden-access-with-docker

Comment: Which files are supposed to be in /var/www/html? I just checked the folder and I only have an index.html file in there.

Comment: did you go into docker and check that?

Comment: This might sound dumb, but what command would I use?

Comment: First, find your docker container name, enter the command docker ps. Then enter this command, docker exec -it container_name /bin/bash once you're there check the contents of /var/www/html and check permissions there

Comment: So I figured out how to do this. Permissions are fine, but when I `ls` inside the container at /var/www/html, I get no files. How do I make the container reflect my files? It is able to build correctly.

Comment: What you do is you go to where your files are at on our server, make sure you are not in Docker container. Find the container name and issue this command #docker cp foo.txt mycontainer:/foo.txt, foo.txt can be index.php so place the file in Docker and give it another try.

Comment: So I ran the following: `docker cp index.php 4fdb84ef3ef4:/index.php` and still the same issue

Comment: you have to copy it to the /var/www/html so the command should be docker cp index.php 4fdb84ef3ef4:/var/www/html/index.php

Comment: This did it. It works now. Thanks for all your help. You can add an answer for me to select if you'd like.

Comment: I'm glad it worked, answer is posted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're missing files in your Docker Container. You need to issue the command below to take your file from your machine to the docker container.

Out of your container issue this command.

```
docker cp index.php 4fdb84ef3ef4:/var/www/html/index.php
```

Comment: This answer is magical. Thank you.

Comment: In my case the project had the typo3 framework/cms, and I had forgotten to 'composer install' first! (and for that also had to import DB first / setup local db properly), this comment helped me out remember this! composer install brought up the necessary files!